# Show that $f(x)=cx$, $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Suppose $$f(x)=\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t(f(x+y)-f(y))dy$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and all $t>0$. Then show that there exists a constant $c$ such that $f(x)=cx$ for all $x$.

My approach: It is given that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous. This implies that by the First Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, we can conclude that $f$ has an antiderivative. Let it be $F$. Therefore, we have $F'(x)=f(x), \forall x\in\mathbb{R}.$ Now $$f(x)=\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t(f(x+y)-f(y))dy=\frac{1}{t}\int_0^tf(x+y)dy-\frac{1}{t}\int_0^tf(y)dy$$ $$=\frac{1}{t}[F(x+y)]_0^t-\frac{1}{t}[F(y)]_0^t=\frac{F(x+t)-F(x)-(F(t)-F(0))}{t}...(1).$$ (1) is due to the second FTC.

It is trivial to note that $f(0)=0$.

This implies that $$f(x)=\frac{F(x+t)-F(x)-(F(t)-F(0))}{t}, \forall x\in\mathbb{R},$$ and $\forall t>0$.

Now consider the function $G:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, such that $$G(x)=\frac{F(x+t)-F(x)}{t}, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$$ and some $t>0$.

Now since $F$ is continuous and differentiable $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$, implies that $G$ is also continuous and differentiable $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Now $$G'(x)=\frac{1}{t}\left\{F'(x+t)-F'(x)\right\},$$ $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Let us choose any $x>0$ and apply MVT on the function $G$ on the interval $[0,x]$. Thus, we can conclude that $\exists c'\in(0,x)$, such that $$G'(c')=\frac{G(x)-G(0)}{x}.$$ This implies that $$G(x)-G(0)=x.G'(c')=x.\frac{1}{t}\left\{F'(c'+t)-F'(c')\right\}$$ $$=x.\frac{1}{t}\left\{f(c'+t)-f(c')\right\}.$$ Now $$G(x)-G(0)=f(x)-f(0)=f(x)$$ $$\implies f(x)=x.\frac{1}{t}\left\{f(c'+t)-f(c')\right\}=x.c$$ where $c=\frac{1}{t}\left\{f(c'+t)-f(c')\right\}$ is a constant.

Therefore $\forall x>0,$ we have $f(x)=cx$ for some constant $c$. A similar analysis for any $x<0$ helps us in concluding that $f(x)=cx,$ $\forall x<0$ and some constant $c$. And we already have $f(0)=0$. But the problem is we have not shown that $c$ is identical $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$. How to show the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $t>0$ we have $tf(x)=\int_0^t(f(x+y)-f(y))dy.$ Differentiation with respect to $t$ gives:

$$(*) \quad f(x)=f(x+t)-f(t)$$

for all $x \in \mathbb R$ and all $t>0.$

With the continuity of $f$ we get, with $t \to 0+$: $f(x)=f(x)-f(0)$, hence $f(0)=0.$

The equation $f(x)=\frac 1 t \int_x^{x+t} f(y) dy-\frac 1 t \int_0^{t} f(y) dy$ shows that $f$ is differentiable.

From $(*)$ we see that for $t>0$ we have

$$ \frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t}=\frac{f(t)}{t}= \frac{f(t)-f(0)}{t}.$$

With $t \to 0+$ we derive $f'(x)=f'(0)$. Hence $f'$ is constant and the assertion follows.

Answer (score 1):

We can write $f(x)=\frac 1 t \int_x^{x+t} f(y) dy-\frac 1 t \int_0^{t} f(y) dy$. Since $f$ is continuous this equation shows that $f$ is differentiable. If $f(x)=c_1x$ for $x >0$ and $f(x)=c_2x$ for $x<0$ then $c_1=c_2$ because $f$ is differentiable at $0$.